# How to detect events using checkcolumn in grid

Tags: javascript, extjs, checkbox

I have a grid, where i use checkcolumn as one of column. If i do some changes, say checkbox on render is unchecked and user check that checkbox. How do i get the changes related to this event. Based on this i have to enable a button in my grid

Comment: I have used grid.getStore().getModifiedRecords(), grid.getStore().getUpdatedRecords() and it gives me an empty value

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1**: [`update`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.0-classic/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-event-update) event on the grid store.

**Method 2**: [`checkchange`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.0-classic/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Check-event-checkchange) event on the checkcolumn.

See both in action: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/s22

Comment: I could achieve my requirement by overriding mu checkcolumn class by referring the link, https://github.com/twinssbc/extjs-CheckColumnPatch . with this how can i override the event `checkchange` in my class